# Security Token Service - which account and permissions should be?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-accounts, security-token-service, service-account

I would like to ask you about Security Token Service, in SharePoint Foundation. Default this service works on user who installed SP but I would like to change this account. Which permissions I have to add to account who will be service account for Security Token?

Thanks for help and support,
Andrzej

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using WSS3.0 or newer so you require the Permission levels for this.

The office site has a good matrix you should keep bookmarked for this very thing.

[Permission levels for WSS3.0](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx)

[Making a new services account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838)

If you are making a separate account for this then you need to give it in most cases full control for SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks your answer but I can't find nothig about Security Token Service and permissions for this service?